# Raspberry Pi 4 native Wifi AC 5GHz not working

Tags: wifi, pi-4

This is my first Raspberry Pi, I'm wondering why it can't connect to my wifi AC network when the specification clearly states it can. I have tried editing the wpa_supplicant.conf file to no avail. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the stuff I gathered below:

**wpa_supplicant:**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=CA

network={
    ssid="ROGERS...-5G"
    psk="..."
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

network={
    ssid="ROGERS...-5G"
    psk="..."
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    disabled=1
}

network={
    ssid="ROGERS..."
    psk="..."
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    disabled=1
}
```

**dmesg Red:**

```
[    4.448389] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    4.448771] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    4.490513] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 1
[    4.678114] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    4.694161] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: May  2 2019 02:46:17 version 7.45.189 (r714228 CY) FWID 01-e1db26e2
```

Comment: Have you set your local country code in your supplicant file? Post the contents of your supplicant file on here (with the password redacted).

Comment: Hi I have just added my edits

Comment: As per this thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1503660

It seems like I may have a defective Pi

Comment: What do you see with `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` why the connection fails?

Comment: Wire it to your router and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade -y`. That will get the new drivers for WiFi on a RPi4B.

Comment: The update didn't work because I've already updated everything

Comment: systemctl doesn't show any errors

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of this command to it: `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue when I changed 5Ghz spec on my router to support AC only. After a lot of digging around, finally found that it works if I set the country to (BO) Bolivia. I don’t know why it works. But I am now able to connect to 5Ghz in ac only mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you all forgot to say that you are using Raspberry PI OS Bullseye version. If not, forget this post.

Take a closer look here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=326626

I have opened this report, but nobody gave me a decent answer.

For me Bullseye is the problem.

see you there.

Comment: Since the thread was over two years old I doubt that the problem is related to the Bullseye release.